# Opening PDF Files in a Browser from search result

Tags: sharepoint-search

The pdf documments from search result do not open in the brower, though yes in acrobat reader client, I make the following changes:

1. I set the web application browser file handling to permissive
2. `$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication <my webapp url>
   $webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add(“application/pdf”)
   $webapp.Update()`
3. I edited the DOCICON.xml file from C:\Program Files\Common
   Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML and I 
   modified the OpenControl to "" so it reads like this:

   Mapping Key="pdf" Value="pdficon_small.png" OpenControl=""/
4. I also used this PS script:

`#Get web application object
    $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "web app url"
    #List all allowed MIME types for this web application
    $webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes
    #Get web application object again
    $webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "web app url"
    #Add PDF to allowed MIME type list
    $webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("application/pdf")
    #Commit changes
    $webapp.Update()`

After applying all the changes I've rebooted the server!

The SharePoint version is 2010 SP2 with last CU 
But nothing made so far to change the behavior of the pdf documents that returns the search component . I should clarify that in the other sites form the web application the pdf open directly in the browser, the problem is given only when I try to open pdf documents from search result.
Someone could help me with this incident?
Thx!

Comment: what version of sharepoint?

Comment: I think that the Microsoft Support Team has found the solution, apply the CU December 2014, which has solved the problem: Issues that this hotfix package fixes -> When you try to open a .pdf file from a search result on a SharePoint 2010 site, the .pdf file is opened in Adobe Reader instead of in the browser. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2910897?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: The problem was solved with the hotfix, thx.

Comment: i added this as answer so that other get benefits.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Microsoft Support Team has found the solution, apply the CU December 2014, which has solved the problem:

Issues that this hotfix package fixes -> When you try to open a .pdf file from a search result on a SharePoint 2010 site, the .pdf file is opened in Adobe Reader instead of in the browser.  [Hotfix KB2910897 for SharePoint Server 2010 December 9, 2014 (](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2910897?wa=wsignin1.0)